# The request is not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration

Tags: javascript, firebase

Tried to login via microsoft provider but after providing my email in the popup I m getting following error:

```
error_description=The request is not valid for the application's 'userAudience' configuration. In order to use /common/ endpoint, the application must not be configured with 'Consumer' as the user audience. The userAudience should be configured with 'All' to use /common/ endpoint.
```

I m not sure where exactly I need to set it as consumer. Here is my code

```
  const provider = new OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log("doLogin then section");
      // User is signed in.
      // IdP data available in result.additionalUserInfo.profile.

      // Get the OAuth access token and ID Token
      const credential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
      const idToken = credential.idToken;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("doLogin", error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's common error
Create a new App Registration with supported account type as "All Microsoft account users" works with any errors.
[image]

Comment: I selected the first option, now getting `unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.`

Comment: Ok, it worked with 3rd option i.e `Accounts in any organization directory ... and personal Microsoft accounts`

Comment: please marked it as accepted answer it will help others